# Install lock in the config file, what does it do?

Tags: ee2

I notice there is a line $config['install_lock'] = ""; in the config file but I cannot find any reference to this in the docs.

What does this do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but I can't test right now. Can you?

I guess it prevents the edition of the `config.php` file by the [Config File Editor](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/config_editor.html): Control Panel > Admin > System Administration > Config File Editor

Comment: Hi Robson, I tried that but I was still able to edit it.

Comment: Maybe EllisLab forgot that line on the file. Write them an email an email.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's to prevent loading the installer interface if there's an 'installer' folder. But may not affect newer EE versions?